# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "IsVisable" : Property does not exists

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamlTest.HelloXamlPage">
  <Label Text="Hello, XAML!"
         VerticalOptions="Start"
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         Rotation="-15"
         IsVisable="true"
         FontSize="Large"
         FontAttributes="Bold"
         TextColor="Black"
         />
</ContentPage>
```

It is a basic example but the thing is this code written on a another Forms XAML Page than the default main XAML page (MainPage.xaml) the default one is working well and there is no problem with is but the other XAML page is not working and give me this exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 9:10. Cannot assign
>   property "IsVisable": Property does not exists, or is not assignable,
>   or mismatching type between value and property

and i have changed the code in the public app

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new XamlTest.HelloXamlPage(); // called HelloXamlPage instead of MainPage();
        }
```

**called HelloXamlPage instead of MainPage();**
so anyone can help me with that?

Comment: You have a typo - its `IsVisible`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a typo. Change `IsVisable` with `IsVisible`

Comment: You also may want to turn on XAML compilation so that you see these kinds of errors when you compile your app. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/